# How manipulate element- and groupwise at the same time in multiindex frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, multi-index

I have the following dataframe:

```
    df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,3,27).reshape((9,3)),\
           index= [['KH','KH','KH','KH','KH','KH','KH','KH','KH'],\
                 ['AOK','AOK','AOK','DOK','DOK','DOK','ROK','ROK','ROK'],\
                 ['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C']],\
           columns=['JE','TE','DE']\
           )
     df.index.names = ['Deck','Status','Urs']
     df
Out[116]: 
                 JE  TE  DE
Deck Status Urs            
KH   AOK    A     1   1   2
            B     1   2   2
            C     2   1   1
     DOK    A     2   2   1
            B     1   2   1
            C     1   2   2
     ROK    A     2   2   2
            B     1   1   2
            C     1   2   1
```

Now i want to simply append a column `'JErel'` to it. This column should contain the values from `'JE'`, but as relative fraction. The fraction should relate to the total sum of the `'Status'` index groups.

I can Access the sum via:

```
df.loc[('KH','AOK')]['JE'].sum()
Out[117]: 4
```

The column should result in something like:

```
1/df.loc[('KH','AOK')]['JE'].sum(),
1/df.loc[('KH','AOK')]['JE'].sum(),
2/df.loc[('KH','AOK')]['JE'].sum() and then, 
2/df.loc[('KH','DOK')]['JE'].sum(), ...
```

,,,,
Thats how far i got.

How do i add the column dynamically like with `apply(Lambda...)` or so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform` to calculate the column *JE* sum which has the same length and index as the original data frame, and then divide *JE* column by it:

```
df['JErel'] = df.JE.div(df.groupby(level=['Deck','Status']).JE.transform('sum'))
df
#                  JE  TE  DE     JErel
# Deck  Status  Urs             
#   KH     AOK  A   2   2   1   0.400000
#               B   2   2   1   0.400000
#               C   1   1   2   0.200000
#          DOK  A   1   1   2   0.250000
#               B   2   1   2   0.500000
#               C   1   1   1   0.250000
#          ROK  A   2   1   2   0.333333
#               B   2   1   2   0.333333
#               C   2   1   1   0.333333
```

Comment: Very beautiful solution. Thank you very much.